# How to generate microwave band frequencies like 85GHz? Is there a DIY device or parts kit to do this?

Tags: microwave, wave, waveguide, magnetron

Let's say I want to build a device that generates and sends out a microwave of some arbitrary specific frequency to a short distance, say 1 - 2 feet. 
For example, 95 GHz. 
Is there a straightforward DIY way to do this? Buying some parts kit, programmable chips, etc.? 
For an experienced DIY hobbyist, what kind of parts and electronic equipment would one need to accomplish this?

Comment: This highly depends on what you want to do with that signal. What output power do you want, do you want to modulate it, and what do you need the signal for?

Comment: You can't independently set wavelength and frequency. If it's 85 GHz, the wavelength is 3.5 mm. If the wavelength is 3 mm, it's 100 GHz.

Comment: Basically, I would like to create a device that can send out a steady 95 GHz electromagnetic wave to about 5 - 10 feet in distance.  That's it.  How would a novice DIY electronics hobbyist do this?  is there a device/transmitter to do this and how would one go about creating a "custom frequency" EM wave of lets say 95 GHz

Comment: https://www.miwv.com/voltage-controlled-oscillators-wide-band-sources-vco-w-band-75ghz-to-110ghz/

Comment: Why do you need the signal?  What do you intend to do with it?  Why particularly 95GHz?  Would a lowe frequency be usable if you could get it easily?

Comment: an amateur radio licence would be a good start.  then you build a fast oscillator  maybe based around a PHEMT

Comment: @Hearth: \$λ = c/(f·n)\$; with n = 1.1667 and f = 85GHz, \$λ ≈ 3mm\$. OP requests a *custom-frequency* generator and a bespoke medium...

Comment: 76 GHz transmitters are inexpensive and easy to get. That might be a good place to start.

Answer (score 3):

Searching for 76 GHz transmitter comes up with many hits, such as the following for a 76-81 GHz device, although it appears to be a sensor:

https://www.ti.com/product/IWR1642

Here is a transmitter for 76-77 GHz:

https://www.nxp.com/docs/en/data-sheet/MC33MR2001TSM.pdf

You might want to read this from the FCC about 70-80-90 GHz systems:

https://www.fcc.gov/wireless/bureau-divisions/broadband-division/microwave-services/millimeter-wave-708090-ghz-service-0

This might be interesting and useful:

http://www.rfdesign.co.uk/microwave/Content/76GHz%20and%20above%20-%20web%20version.pdf

Here is a 95-100 GHz transceiver:
https://www.miwv.com/95-ghz-to-100-ghz-w-band-transceiver/

These are not meant as product recommendations, but they may provide insight into what may be necessary to achieve the OP's desires.

Answer (score 2):

For such a high frequency and relatively high power you would need to use a device called magnetron, similar to the one found in microwave ovens, but that would require high voltages which even experienced and knowledgeable technicians would rather not mess with.

Ultra high frequencies are something that requires a lot of knowledge, understanding and skill, in other words a good level of expertise to deal with successfully, and if you don't even know how to generate them then you're out of your league.

I am not aware of a DIY kit for such high frequencies, especially if it involves anything more than a few milliwatts.

Comment: What if it were (say) only 0.25 mW? Would you be aware of something?